# Can I use transactions with ALTER TABLE?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, phpmyadmin, rollback

I'm a beginner (actually newbie) to SQL transactions, so I may be missing something obvious.

I have this SQL code, that I'm trying to run through *phpMyAdmin*:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(NULL, 'User A', 'user.a@example.com', '4', 'User A');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(NULL, 'User B', 'user.b@example.com', '3', 'User B');

ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `level` `level` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `number` `number` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD COLUMN `number` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AFTER `id`;

COMMIT;
```

Second `ALTER` causes `#1054 - Unknown column 'number' in 'users'` error.

But, when it happens in *phpMyAdmin*, I can see, that first two `INSERT`s (or the entire transaction) is not rolled back. The `users` table does contain two new records.

What am I missing? phpMyAdmin doesn't support transactions? Or I don't understand, how transactions actually work, and this is pretty normal, that these two `INSERT`s are not rolled back in case of error?

Comment: FWIW this works fine in Postgres, and is one reason some people prefer Postgres over MySQL.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Some statements (most notably [DDL](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Language/Definitions:_what_are_DDL,_DML_and_DQL%3F)) in MySQL [cause an implicit commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html) *before* they are executed and [cannot be rolled back](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html) - as such this prevents the prior DML changes from being rolled back as well.

> The statements listed in this section (and any synonyms for them) *implicitly end any transaction active in the current session, as if you had done a COMMIT before executing the statement*. As of MySQL 5.5.3, most of these statements also cause an implicit commit after executing; for additional details, see the end of this section.

Since `ALTER TABLE` is one of the affected statements, the the SQL batch is effectively treated as:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(NULL, 'User A', 'user.a@example.com', '4', 'User A');

COMMIT; -- prevents ROLLBACK of insert(s), even if DDL fails
ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `level` `level` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

The suggested solution is to [keep DDL and DML separated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4797958/2864740). The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html) says:

> You should design your [DML] transactions not to include such [DDL] statements. If you issue a statement early in a transaction that cannot be rolled back, and then another statement later fails, the full effect of the transaction cannot be rolled back in such cases by issuing a ROLLBACK statement.

Comment: Why MySQL decides to `COMMIT` before executing statement? Shouldn't it fail stating that transaction needs to be explicitly closed.

Comment: The implicit commit — as opposed to raising an error — likely stems from historical design / decisions and lost in antiquity. While an argument can be made either way, it’s usually not easy or productive to re-create the context in which various implementation choices were made.