# Difference between Laravel's raw SQL functions

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

It seems I'm not the only person struggling with the differences between Laravel's DB::raw(), DB::select(), DB::statement(), and DB::unprepared() methods.  It seems as if one almost needs to try a given SQL statement with all 4 to identify which will work.  Can anybody clarify how they relate to each other, and which to use for what purposes?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I will try to clarify:

#### DB::raw()

It generates a raw and sanitized SQL string, to be passed to other query/statements, preventing SQL injections. Is to be used with all of the and never alone. And you should never send a not sanitized string to your query/statements.

```
DB::select(DB::raw('select * from whatever'));
```

#### DB::select()

Is for simple selects:

```
DB::select(DB::raw('select * from whatever'));
```

#### DB::statement()

I think it work with selects, but should be used for non SQL query commands:

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('update whatever set valid = true;'));
```

#### DB::unprepared()

All SQL commands in Laravel are prepared by default, but sometimes you need to execute a command in an unprepared mode, because some commands in some database cannot be ran in prepared mode. Here's an issue I opened about this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/53

```
DB::unprepared(DB::raw('update whatever set valid = true;'));
```

Comment: You made a little mistake in `DB::raw` - it generates **non sanitized** string and **does not** prevent injections. Also `DB::statement` could accept some commands/statements, like `set @var = 0`. However for most it should be `unprepared` like you said.

Comment: For DB::statement() what do you mean by, "should be used for non SQL query commands"?

Comment: What to use when we call a stored procedure, `DB::select` or `DB::statement`?
For example: `DB::select('call storedProcedure(?,?)',array($a,$b));` or `DB::statement('call storedProcedure(?,?)',array($a,$b));` ?

Comment: @SyedHaziqHamdaniboth DB::statement and DB::unprepared return only booleans.

Answer (score 3):

More Correct Answer (I Think) For Laravel >= 5.0

**DB::raw()**

Produces "raw" which means "non-sanitized" string. That's why on [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions) there is a warning:

[image: laravel docs warning about using raw strings in db queries]

**DB::select() , DB::insert() , DB::update() , DB::delete()**

These are the practical methods that Laravel offers which run prepared statements.

**DB::statement()**

This is again for running prepared statements which are not specific to CRUD.

*[The methods which use prepared statements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#running-queries) provide protection for SQL injection whereas this responsibility belongs to the programmer when using [raw expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions).*

**DB::unprepared()**

There is no information about it on Laravel Docs and very little information on internet. Nevertheless I have tested it considering the answer above and this:

[Laravel, create MySQL trigger from Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410909/laravel-create-mysql-trigger-from-migration/27418738)

e.g. I have tried to create a MySQL trigger with DB::statement() method first but it gave me this error when migrating:

```
  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if
your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.")
      C:\wamp64\www\oscared-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\wamp64\www\oscared-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
```

However, when I tested it using DB::unprepared(), it worked smoothly. (Laravel 5.8)