# How to add user to another table after user registration in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.6, user-registration

I am developing an e-commerce project in **Laravel 5.6** in which I have two tables for users :

1. **Users** for passwords and some other stuff and
2. **UserDetails** table for storing user address, phone, city, pin code, etc.

While registering a user with storing credentials in the **Users** table I want to make a column in the **UserDetails** table with the same user_id that has been generated while adding to **Users** table.

Below is my migrations :

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });


Schema::create('user_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('pincode')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I had tried to add following in the **create** function in **RegisterController**

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {   
        User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        UserDetails::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
        ]);

        return;
    }
```

But it doesn't work and shows

`Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"`.

Help me through this.

Comment: Why dont you write a trigger? When user gets added, trigger adds it to other table

Comment: @EssKay I think that is the part of the database. Is this is possible with Laravel?

Comment: yes. definately

Comment: also, auth::has nothing at the moment since you are only creating it, not authenticating user. thats where you get the error

Comment: Triggers in laravel https://stackoverflow.com/a/27418738/2267583

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of @MateusJunges is correct but the error you got after doing is that

> "Add [user_id] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on
>   [App\UserDetails]."

In order to resolve this error I have to add this code to my **UserDetails** model :

```
protected $fillable = [
        'user_id'
    ];
```

You can refer [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment).

After that all the code of @MateusJunges is correct.

Comment: I already have the fillable array with name like `protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 
    ];`, but it shows an error `Add [name] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User]` . Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: @VishnuJayan I think you have to add `$fillable` to the `App\User` also. If that's not the error consider asking a new question providing details of the error.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the `create` function, on `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`,

which is, by default:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Just change this to

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
    UserDetails::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id
    ]);

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @MateusJunges your code is correct which I had already tried before but this time I got the error which I had solved in my answer.

Comment: Yes, you must add the add the user_id to fillable property, but, looking to your question's code, specifcally where you try to create a new UserDetails record whti UserDetails::create(), i  thought you had already done that, once it is required to allow the mass assignment.