# Laravel 5 DB::statement return SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

Here is statement:

```
    $statement = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE homestead.temp_table
        AS
        SELECT title,content, feed, link, 'date', created_at, updated_at FROM homestead.news ORDER BY 'date' ASC LIMIT 5;
        TRUNCATE homestead.news;
        INSERT INTO homestead.news (title, content, feed, link, 'date', created_at, updated_at)
        SELECT title, content, feed, link, 'date', created_at, updated_at FROM homestead.temp_table;
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE homestead.temp_table;";

            try {
                DB::statement($statement);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
```

Code is working in Mysql Workbench but not inside laravel.
Please help, this is my first question on Stackoverflow :)

full error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRUNCATE homestead.news; INSERT INTO homestead.news (title, content, feed, l' at line 4 (SQL: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE homestead.temp_table AS SELECT title,content, feed, link, `date`, created_at, updated_at FROM homestead.news ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 5; TRUNCATE homestead.news; INSERT INTO homestead.news (title, content, feed, link, `date`, created_at, updated_at) SELECT title, content, feed, link, `date`, created_at, updated_at FROM homestead.temp_table; DROP TEMPORARY TABLE homestead.temp_table;)
```

Comment: What is the reset of the error message? ... Please append to the question, not as another comment.

Comment: What do you mean by  "reset of the error message" ?

Answer (score 0):

**solution** was to change DB::statement to DB::unprepared.

more info here:

[Difference between Laravel's raw SQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346162/difference-between-laravels-raw-sql-functions)