# transaction doesn't work on truncate

Tags: laravel, transactions, laravel-5

I'm trying Laravel transaction for the first time... I do most of my queries with Eloquent and since there no transaction there I have to do a mixture of Eloquent and query builder.

Here is my code:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try{
    Setting::truncate();
    Setting::insert($data);
    DB::commit();
    jok('all ok');

}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    DB::rollback();
    jerror('some error accorded! ');
}
```

So I've tied to add some invalid data to Settings and i got the `some error accorded` error as expected but the query before  INSERT `Setting::truncate();` was executed anyway and I ended up with a empty table.

So either I'm doing something wrong or transaction doesn't work on truncate.

Comment: i have the same case on server side

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TRUNCATE TABLE in a database transaction will cause a implicit COMMIT action. DELETE does not have that same behavior, so you can safely run

```
DELETE FROM tblname
```

This will clear your table and still keep the desired rollback feature of a transaction.

See the MySQL documentation on TRUNCATE. The bullet points explain this functionality http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html

Answer (score 3):

A better solution to do `delete` is to use Model method:

```
Setting::query()->delete();
```

Comment: Why is this a better solution?

Comment: Hi, for two reason: 1. it use Eloquent classes instead of raw SQL, 2. truncate is not rolled back in a transaction, but delete is